# Why should differentiate the five levels yum repo, what's their respective responsibilities?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

There is a `CentOS.repo` configuration:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
baseurl=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
baseurl=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
baseurl=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

You see, here we have `5` levels of the repo.  But I cannot find the `http://mirror.scalabledns.com/centos/7/contrib/` directory.

I have several questions:

1. What are the 5 levels repo source? What's their function? Why should we differentiate them?
2. Why there is no `contrib`? If there is none, how should I config? Does it matter if I do not config?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the 5 levels repo source? what's their function? why should differentiate them?

Disgracefully copied from [centoshelp.org](https://centoshelp.org/resources/repos/), [cannot backquote all of the contents]

- **Base Repository**:
  `[Base]` – The packages that make up Centos, as it is released on the ISOs. It is enabled by default
- **Updates Repository:**
  `[Updates]` – Updated packages to [Base] released after the Centos ISOs. This will be Security, BugFix, or Enhancements to the [Base] software. It is enabled by default
- **Extras:**
  `[Extras]` – Packages built and maintained by the Centos developers that add functionality to the core distribution. These packages have undergone some basic testing, should track upstream release versions fairly closely and will never replace any core distribution package. It is enabled by default
- **Centosplus Repository:**
  `[Centosplus]` – Packages contributed by Centos developers and the users. These packages might replace rpm’s included in the core distribution. You should understand the implications of enabling and using packages from this repository. It is disabled by default
- **Contrib Repository:**
  `[Contrib]` – Packages contributed by the Centos Users, which do not overlap with any of the core distribution packages. These packages have not been tested by the Centos developers, and may not track upstream version releases very closely. It is disabled by default

> Why there is no contrib, if there is no it, what should I config for it, is it matter if I do not config?

As from the answer above you can see that it is not enabled by default because the packages under this repo are not tested by centos developers. So you can use them at your own risk. You can enable it just by changing `0` to `1` at place of `enabled=0`.